# pandas attribute error : no attribute 'Factor' found

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to run code provided by yhat [in their article about random forests in Python](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/random-forests-in-python.html), but I keep getting following error message:

```
File "test_iris_with_rf.py", line 11, in <module>
    df['species'] = pd.Factor(iris.target, iris.target_names)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Factor'
```

Code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
print df
print iris.target_names
df['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df)) <= .75

df['species'] = pd.Factor(iris.target, iris.target_names)

df.head()
```

Answer (score 47):

In newer versions of pandas, the `Factor` is called `Categorical` instead. Change your line to:

```
df['species'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(iris.target, iris.target_names)
```

Answer (score 8):

Categorical variables seems to be one of the more active areas of development in pandas, so I believe it's changed yet again in pandas 0.15.0 :

```
df['species'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(iris.target, iris.target_names)
```

(I lacked sufficient reputation to add this as a comment on David Robinson's answer)

Comment: Don't worry, there's only a finite set of names it can assume }:>

Answer (score 0):

```
def factor(series):
    #input should be a pandas series object
    dic = {}
    for i,val in enumerate(series.value_counts().index):
        dic[val] = i
    return [ dic[val] for val in series.values ]
```